# Show lowest price simple product from configurable product outside of product page

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, sorting, simple-product

I have a configurable product with a number of simple products associated with it.

I am showing the lowest price simple product on the product page with this code:

```
$conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product); 
$simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions()->addAttributeToSort('Price', 'asc'); 

foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){ 
echo '</br>Price: ' . Mage::helper('core')->currency($simple_product->getPrice()) . '</br></br>';
break;
}
```

I have a banner on the homepage which is where I want to show the price for a certain product.

I need to modify this code to load the price from configurable product ID 80 and show it on the Homepage

Comment: are you need lowest price simple product in homepage banner right?

Comment: Yes. I need to pull data using the product ID if that's possible

Comment: configurable product ID fixed?

Comment: It doesnt change as far as I'm aware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try bellow code

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(80);
if($_product->isconfigurable()) {
    $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product); 
    $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addFilterByRequiredOptions()
                        ->addAttributeToSort('Price', 'asc'); 

    foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){ 
    echo '</br>Price: ' . Mage::helper('core')->currency($simple_product->getPrice()) . '</br></br>';
    break;
    }   
}
```